# Why xts object produced bad forecasted values in comparision to ts object in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

For the testing purpose, I have created two time series object with same frequency (frequency=12) using `xts()` and `ts()` from the same dataset and used `auto.arima()` function for forecasting next 30 values. The `xts` based time series object produced bad forecasted values in comparison to `ts`.

I have a high frequency dataset in seconds over 72 hours. For creating dateTime (2001:02:01  12:01:00) timestamp, I need to use `xts` object for creating time series.

How can I improve the forecasted results in `xts` based time series forecasting?

Comment: `forecast::auto.arima` expects a `ts` object, not an `xts` object. If the object it receives isn't `ts`, it will try to convert it to `ts`. This doesn't preserve the `frequency` attribute, which means that it is then treated as yearly data and seasonality is not considered and a different ARIMA model may be chosen. Why did you set the frequency to 12 if your data is in seconds?

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have set 12 frequency in testing dataset. In my orginal dataset, i have created time series object with 60 frequency. How can get the forecasted values along timestamp (like that2001:02:01 12:01:00) from the ts object?